# sed command appends characters onto end of error message

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to make a script that runs through a list of paths provided from a file and edits a URL in each file, but I've run into a strange issue. Here's a reproducible example.

```
read -r line < paths.txt
echo $line
sed -i 's/word/otherword/' $line
```

The paths are coming from paths.txt, which simply contains one line that reads `bat.properties`
 with a newline character.

The output of the script is below.

```
$ bash urlReplacer.sh
bat.properties
: No such file or directoryies
```

For reference, the error sed produces in this case would normally be `sed: No such file or directory`. By changing the `bat.properties` line, I've confirmed that the 'ies' in 'properties' is the part that's being appended to the end of the error, but I really don't know what's going on with the missing 'sed' at the beginning. As you can also see, `bat.properties` is read in perfectly. I'm guessing this is an issue with sed misuse, but I'm not sure where the issue lies.

Comment: Redirect the output of `bash urlReplacer.sh` to a file and inspect its content using an editor (`vi`, for example). I suspect there is nothing added to the error message but, on screen, it overwrites the beginning of the second line of text. A [<CR>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character included in the error message (at the end of the `bat.properties` string included in the error message) sends the cursor to the beginning of the line and the rest of the error message overwrites its beginning. Is the `paths.txt` file generated on Windows?

Comment: `dos2unix paths.txt` will probably fix it. Good luck.

Comment: Soo also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think paths.txt has DOS line endings, also known as `\r` or `^M`.
Delete them first or in your script. You can use `dos2unix`, `tr -d '\r'` or:

```
IFS=$'\r' read -r line : < paths.txt
echo "$line"
sed -i 's/word/otherword/' "$line"
```

I quoted `line` for filenames with a space.